# ng-class if object exists angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angular-directive

How can we activate class if object exists. i have a json array where i need to activate a class if image_id exists for that particular array.

```
something like ng-if="data.image_id"  then class get activated

 <div class="test" ng-class="classonimage:data.image_id">
   //showing data

<div>
```

Here class test is active but classonimage would be activated to modify few css attributes if image_id exists.

So here i want to make some change to story if it contains image. How can we activate ng-class on ng-if.
 How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
<div class="test" ng-class="{'classonimage':data.image_id}"><div>
```

It's important to place class name between ' ', because if class name contains `-` ng-class will not work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YwU77/1/

Answer (score 2):

Check if `data.image_id` is defined or not, and correct your syntax for [`ngClass`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass):

```
<div class="test" ng-class="{classonimage : data.image_id !== undefined}"></div>
```

Comment: `!==` throws an error in the console, at least it used to. It does not seem to like triple equal to either. You have to use `!=` and `==` (had to, not sure if it was fixed)

Comment: @callmekatootie It doesn't anymore, for a long time now!

Comment: @Blackhole It will not work if class name is like `class-on-image`.

Comment: @czwek Seems obvious, but it's worth mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-class="{classonimage:data.image_id}` to control the class of this element.

Here is the example [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/iKLdIzn9j5oPOSa8wVHc) :

You will see the class applies the font-size(in style.css) if data.image_id is true.